# How do i prevent thesame action to run on other parts of my webpage simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, onclick, display

I wrote a code javascript code that will display the complete write up of a particular text which happens to be in three location in my html, but instead of displaying just the particular one that was clicked, its displaying others along [codepen](https://codepen.io/techietimmy-ux/pen/rNRYmgx) side. [code screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmf2D.png)

i was trying to make an hidden text non hidden upon clicking of the read more with bold print for individaul read me. check right side of my screen shot for the result

```
const readMore = document.querySelectorAll('.readMore')
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.moreRead')

// const content = document.querySelector('.moreRead')


readMore.forEach((read, index) => {
  
  read.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(index);
    read.classList.add('d-none');


    // content.classList.remove('d-none')

    contents.forEach(content =>{
      content.classList.remove('d-none')
    })
    

  })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because when any one of `.readMore` are clicked you loop over *every* `.moreRead` and display them - not only the one which is related to the clicked element.

To fix this, you can use `parentElement` and `querySelector()` to target the sibling of the clicked `.readMore` and updated its class:

```js
const readMore = document.querySelectorAll('.readMore');

readMore.forEach((read, index) => {
  read.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    read.classList.add('d-none');
    read.parentElement.querySelector('.moreRead').classList.remove('d-none');
  })
})
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card mt-5 border-0" style="background-color: #eee984;">
  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="/assets/card-one-image.jpg" alt="Title">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Business Development</h5>
    <p class="card-text fw-bold fs-5">The new way to fast track business operations isnot somthing</p>
    <p class="card-text">
      The new way to fast track business operations in an economic crises is not something
      <span class="readMore fw-bold" style="cursor: pointer;">....Read More</span>
      <span class="moreRead d-none">
        card 1 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Laborum, cupiditate aspernatur nam voluptate deleniti explicabo
        totam rem. Accusantium molestiae vero voluptatum a, fuga repudiandae, rem saepe
        nobis maiores quisquam eligendi.
        Animi inventore exercitationem soluta magni iure, odit rem sed, porro dolore ut
        totam itaque. Eum nemo sint fugiat tempore saepe inventore rerum, quis minus vel
        sunt voluptate doloremque dignissimos cum.
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 100%;" class="img-fluid mt-3 me-2" src="/assets/alexander-krivitskiy-TD9rSZywT7Y-unsplash.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div>
      <div class="fw-bold mt-2">joanne david</div>
      <p>11 jan 2022 -5mins read</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card mt-5 border-0" style="background-color: #eee984;">
  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="/assets/card-one-image.jpg" alt="Title">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Business Development</h5>
    <p class="card-text fw-bold fs-5">The new way to fast track business operations isnot somthing</p>
    <p class="card-text">
      The new way to fast track business operations in an economic crises is not something
      <span class="readMore fw-bold" style="cursor: pointer;">....Read More</span>
      <span class="moreRead d-none">
        card 1 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Laborum, cupiditate aspernatur nam voluptate deleniti explicabo
        totam rem. Accusantium molestiae vero voluptatum a, fuga repudiandae, rem saepe
        nobis maiores quisquam eligendi.
        Animi inventore exercitationem soluta magni iure, odit rem sed, porro dolore ut
        totam itaque. Eum nemo sint fugiat tempore saepe inventore rerum, quis minus vel
        sunt voluptate doloremque dignissimos cum.
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 100%;" class="img-fluid mt-3 me-2" src="/assets/alexander-krivitskiy-TD9rSZywT7Y-unsplash.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div>
      <div class="fw-bold mt-2">joanne david</div>
      <p>11 jan 2022 -5mins read</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood about what you're trying to do;
You have three sections each with a read more button to toggle that section's visibility on or off.

However in your toggle buttons click event listeners, you turn on the visibility of all the collapsible sections by removing the d-none class. What you should instead do is remove the d-none class from only the section the toggle button controls.

Comment: That is exactly what the OP is asking. The question still remains - how do they do that?